# How to perform conditional average in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel-formula

I have a big dataset something like this below:

```
Image    | Length | Angel
-------------------------------- 
DSC_001  | 233.22 |2.00
--------------------------------
DSC_001  | 24.897 |1.2
--------------------------------
DSC_001  | 28.55  |2.87
--------------------------------
DSC_002  | 23.76  |3.71
--------------------------------
DSC_002  | 34.21  |3.21
---------------------------------
```

I want to do average of `Length` and `Angles` for each set (DSC_001 is one set, DSC_002 is another and so on).

I can do it manually in Excel but taking huge time when it around 4000 data point.

I like to know how I do it in R or in Excel in much smarter way?

Comment: Do you use R regularly? i.e. do you know how to read this data into R?

Comment: Use pivot table in Excel

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(image) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean) , by = image]
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~image, df1, FUN = mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Excel**:

1. Make a new list with the unique values in the `Image` column as decribed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2).
2. Add the column names above your new list (not mandatory but important for clear presentation of the data).
3. Use `AVERAGEIF()` to compute a conditioned average with the formula: `=AVERAGEIF(A2:A10,E3,B2:B10)` assuming `A2:A10` is the column `Image`, `B2:B10` is The column of the values to calculate their mean, and `E3` is the cell where the Image to calculate its' mean is stored.

Here is a screenshot to clarify this:
[image: Using AVERAGEIF()]

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @jit-c Please consider [voting up or marking this as the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem, so it will help others ;)